# Set same y-lim for multi panel plot using plot_model()

Tags: r, ggplot2, sjplot

I have created a multi-panel plot using plot_model(). However, the scale limits on the y_axis came different for each panel.

I first run a model fm then plot the predicted values:

```
p <-  plot_model(
  fm,
  type = c("pred"),
  terms = c("Trial","CS [-0.9,0,0.9]", "Prof[-10.9,0,10.9]", "Congr"))
```

Then I wanted to get same y-axis scale (limits) on all panels:

```
 p + ggplot2::scale_y_continuous(limits = c(5.9, 6.2))
```

but this didn't work!

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks!
That seems to work but only if I minimize the panels, that is having each panel on a separate plot:

[Panel1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hK0x.png)
[Panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrWCh.png)

When I want to show both panels in the same plot and with the Y-limits desired, nothing changes.

[Panels 1&2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0UyS.png)

Is this because the size of the plot is limited?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
df <- structure(list(Subject = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), Log_RT = c(5.955837369, 6.228511004, 5.874930731, 
5.84932478, 5.780743516, 5.866468057, 5.424950017, 5.81711116, 
5.899897354, 5.834810737, 5.683579767, 5.655991811, 5.624017506, 
5.459585514, 5.697093487, 5.934894196, 5.802118375, 5.834810737, 
5.789960171, 5.631211782, 5.796057751, 5.669880923, 5.549076085, 
5.81711116, 6.03068526, 6.040254711, 5.81711116, 5.80814249, 
5.863631176, 5.641907071, 6.033086222, 6.021023349, 6.470799504, 
6.380122537, 6.424869024, 6.29156914, 6.061456919, 6.502790046, 
6.282266747, 6.311734809, 6.455198563, 6.259581464, 6.570882962, 
6.371611847, 6.570882962, 6.483107351, 6.333279628, 6.455198563, 
6.469250317, 6.289715571, 6.285998095, 6.442540166, 6.289715571, 
6.395261598, 6.152732695, 6.415096959, 6.352629396, 6.270988432, 
6.210600077, 6.311734809, 6.059123196, 6.208590026), CSC = c(-0.562217385, 
-0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, 
-0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, 
-0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, 
-0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, 
-0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, 
-0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.562217385, -0.145550719, 
-0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, 
-0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, 
-0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, 
-0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, 
-0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, 
-0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, -0.145550719, 
-0.145550719), Trial = c(-14.60970149, -13.60970149, -12.60970149, 
-11.60970149, -10.60970149, -9.609701493, -8.609701493, -7.609701493, 
-6.609701493, -5.609701493, -4.609701493, -3.609701493, -2.609701493, 
-1.609701493, -0.609701493, 0.390298507, 1.390298507, 2.390298507, 
3.390298507, 4.390298507, 6.390298507, 7.390298507, 8.390298507, 
9.390298507, 10.39029851, 11.39029851, 12.39029851, 13.39029851, 
14.39029851, 15.39029851, -15.60970149, -14.60970149, -13.60970149, 
-12.60970149, -11.60970149, -10.60970149, -9.609701493, -8.609701493, 
-7.609701493, -6.609701493, -5.609701493, -4.609701493, -3.609701493, 
-2.609701493, -1.609701493, -0.609701493, 0.390298507, 1.390298507, 
2.390298507, 3.390298507, 4.390298507, 5.390298507, 6.390298507, 
7.390298507, 8.390298507, 9.390298507, 10.39029851, 11.39029851, 
12.39029851, 13.39029851, 14.39029851, 15.39029851), Congr.d = c(1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), ProC = c(7.814814815, 
7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 
7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 
7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 
7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 
7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 
7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 7.814814815, 12.25925926, 
12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 
12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 
12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 
12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 
12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 
12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 12.25925926, 
12.25925926)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -62L))
```

For the plot:

```
library(jtools)
library(sjPlot)
library(pbkrtest)

fm <- lmer(Log_RT ~ Congr.d*CSC*Trial*ProC +
              (1+Congr.d||Subject), data=df)

summ(fm)



plot_model(fm, type = c("pred"),terms = c("Trial","CSC [-0.2,0,0.2]",
 "ProC[-2.2,0,2.2]", "Congr.d[0,1]"),axis.lim=c(6.2,6.8))
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QtdHT.png)

You can see that the Y-axis limits is not as indicated in the code.

Comment: fm = lm(mpg ~ .,data=mtcars) ; 
plot_model(fm,type="pred",terms=c("hp","disp","wt"),axis.lim=list(c(0,400),c(0,40)))

Comment: this worked for me, as well as what you have.. something weird about your model?

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work but only if I minimize the panels, that is having each panel on a separate plot:
Panel1 https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hK0x.png;                                                Panel2 https://i.stack.imgur.com/CrWCh.png
When I want to show both panels in the same plot and with the Y-limits desired, nothing changes.
Panels 1&2    https://i.stack.imgur.com/X0UyS.png
Is this because the size of the plot is limited?

Comment: Hi Sousou it's hard to figure out what went wrong without a reproducible example. I guess you used cowplot or something else to put them together? Can you share the data, i.e what you used to produce fm and how you try to put them together?

Comment: Where should I upload the data?

Comment: dput(<your data frame>) and paste the output in the post above?

Comment: This rendered a very long output, longer than the number of characters allowed in the post!  my data has 4021 obs. Sorry, I am still new to this!

Comment: Hey @Sousou, hmmm ok how did you put the plots together? Or can you try to only put data that will reproduce the problem?

Comment: Hey, I have edited the original post with some reproducible data and what I did to generate the plot. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Daniel, plot() worked perfectly!  How can I get rid of the plot title? adding (title = " ") inside the code or  (%>% plot(show.title = FALSE) to the code didn't work? Any better idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the [ggeffects-package](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/), which is internally used by **sjPlot** to create effects-plots. **ggeffects** gives you some more flexibility according to plot-customization. In your case, you can simply use arguments that are passed down to `ggplot2::scale_y_continuous()`, see details [in this vignette](https://strengejacke.github.io/ggeffects/articles/introduction_plotcustomize.html#changing-the-y-axis-appearance):

```r
library(lme4)
library(ggeffects)

fm <- lmer(Log_RT ~ Congr.d*CSC*Trial*ProC + (1+Congr.d||Subject), data=df)
pr <- ggpredict(fm, terms = c("Trial","CSC [-0.2,0,0.2]", "ProC[-2.2,0,2.2]", "Congr.d[0,1]"))
plot(pr, limits = c(6.0, 7.0))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-12-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Daniel, plot() worked perfectly well! How can I get rid of the plot title? adding (title = " ") inside the code or (%>% plot(show.title = FALSE) to the code didn't work? Any better idea?

Comment: You get a ggplot-object, so simply add something like `... + ggtitle("")` or `... + labs(title = NULL)`.

Comment: Sorry, where should I add this?  I put ggtitle("") in multiple places and got error message. Can you please specify where this goes?

Comment: `library(ggplot2); plot(pr, limits = c(6.0, 7.0)) + labs(title = NULL)`

Comment: Yes, that's what I did but the plot title still there and I got an error message: "Error in plot(pr, limits = c(5.95, 6.2)) + labs(title = NULL) : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator"

Comment: However this worked:  plot(pr, show.title = FALSE, limits = c(6.0, 7.0)). Thanks so much!

Comment: Yes, sorry, forgot that in your case you have multiple plots, so you get a list of plots. But of course, `show.title` works as well.